# How to Deserialize a JSON and serialize a specific String value pair as different JSON?

Tags: json, serialization, gson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

The Json body I want to deserialize is something like below

```
{
"status": "OK",
"place_id": "07e0a63d862b2982e4c4b7e655f148d2",
"scope": "APP"
}
```

Below is the Json body I want to build from above Json after deserializing it

```
{
"place_id": "07e0a63d862b2982e4c4b7e655f148d2"
}
```

Comment: So you only want to keep the `"place_id"`? Is the JSON body you have provided in the question the complete JSON body or is it the element of an (nested) array or object?

Comment: It's a complete JSON body which I received as a response @Marcono1234

Answer (score 0):

Because your JSON data appears to be rather small you could use Gson's [`JsonParser.parseString(String)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html#parseString(java.lang.String)) method to parse the data into an in-memory representation, then copy the relevant JSON object member to a new [`JsonObject`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) and serialize that to JSON using [`Gson.toJson(JsonElement)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(com.google.gson.JsonElement)):

```java
JsonObject original = JsonParser.parseString(json).getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject copy = new JsonObject();
// Might also have to add some validation to make sure the member
// exists and is a string
copy.add("place_id", original.get("place_id"));

String transformedJson = new Gson().toJson(copy);
```

If this solution turns out to not be efficient enough for you, you could also have a look at [`JsonReader`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) and [`JsonWriter`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html).